# Limit superior and limit inferior (Definition)

Tags: real-analysis

What's the definition of limit superior and limit inferior for a function $f:\bar{\Omega}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded and smooth?

Sorry, I edited the ask.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: I didn't see a definition there in this case @Siminore.

Comment: I can see a section called: Functions from metric spaces to metric spaces

Comment: Indeed, but I can't read. Thanks @Siminore.

Comment: [Here's an earlier version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior&oldid=605629362) which seems to work.

Comment: Thanks @fuglede, but if I have $\lim sup_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)$?

Comment: What I do if $\lim sup_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)$ @Siminore?

Comment: Just replace the neighborhood of $a$ with the standard neighborhood of infinity: $B(\infty,R) = \{x \mid \|x\| > R\}$.

Comment: Ok, I will try in this way, thanks @Siminore.